# Pointer type error

Tags: c

I'm playing around with shared memory and getting this error:

```
Line 38 [Warning] passing arg 1 of `munmap' from incompatible pointer type.
```

I've done some googling, but not getting anywhere. I'm guessing it's something to do with using an incorrect data type somewhere...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
int     fd, i, len = 1;
off_t   off = 0;
int    *pMem, c;
// initialize device file
fd = open("mapfile", (O_CREAT | O_RDWR), 0666 );
if( fd < 0 )
{
    perror("open(fmap)");
    exit(1);
}

c = 1;
write( fd, &c, 10);

// map the file to memory
pMem = (int *)mmap( (void*)0, len,
             (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE),  MAP_SHARED, fd, off);

printf("pMem is %p\n", pMem);
c = 1;
for( i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    *pMem = c;
    sleep(1);
    printf("%d: c=%d *pMem = %d\n", getpid(), c, *pMem);
    c++ ;
}

munmap(pMem, len);
close(fd);

exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `#include <unistd.h>` but, otherwise, I get clean compilation and am unable to reproduce your problem

Comment: I removed (void*) from pMem = (int *)mmap( (void*) and now it works. ps I don't know what I doing

Comment: Your original warning was on the `munmap` line. So, changing the `mmap` shouldn't affect that. BTW, you can use [and should use] backticks for code fragments in comments. Without them, they can be interpreted as markdown escapes, notably `*` can get lost because a `**` is a **bold** directive. Also, I'm a bit mystified [and I've been doing C for many years] because your code should compile cleanly. What OS and compiler are you using? You tagged with `c` but could you be using `c++` [likely on Windows]?

Comment: I'm on windows using gcc. I don't really know the difference between c and c++ This is for a uni assignment which I'm finding hard as I don't have a passion or an interest in coding

Comment: Re. windows I suspected as much. In windows, it doesn't really have a credible c compiler. Even if it says "c", it's actually "c++". Given that, c++ is more finicky about casting of pointers. In c, we'd want `(void *) 0`. In c++, we'd want `0`. This is c++'s "quirk" to get around it's _stricter_ type casting [laborous explanation suppressed :-)]. You ended up doing the right thing. In the standard `.h` files, they have conditionals to do `#define NULL ((void *) 0)` for c and `#define NULL 0` for c++. Even that breaks in c++, so now they have `nullptr`. I despise c++, because of this nonsense

Comment: Too bad about the lack of passion, which is _essential_ to being a good programmer. Coding is _hard_ to do without it. A suggestion: Think of a program [_any_ program] that _you_ would _love_ to create--one you _could_ be passionate about. When I started, it was an IRC chat program, for a friend it was an email program, another was a file archive program, another a language compiler. We worked on these endlessly because we each _loved_ the program we were doing. This fervor got us over the dark days when the bugs were impossible to find. We developed skill along the way ...

Comment: With that skill, other programs were much easier to write. Our "passion programs" allowed us work through the drudge long enough to become proficient. With that, the coding became easy/faster because what used to take an hour, suddenly, took 10 seconds. I have a saying about programming: If it's _hard_, you're doing it _wrong_. And, you're missing the joy ...

Comment: Lack of passion and interest are probably the wrong words, I think I'm just getting frustrated with this course and this assignment. It has been taught really bad!

Comment: One final [loving] thought. From your code, you're just starting out. Coding will be hard for a while. But, it will get easier. Downhill snow skiing isn't much fun when you can only do a snowplow and fall down every ten feet. That _isn't_ skiing. But, eventually you learn how to do full parallel turns and can rocket down the mountain at high speed. That _is_ skiing. To be direct, you can't say "I don't have a passion or interest in coding"--because you're _not_ coding, you're "face planting" in the snow. You need more skill--after that, you can say you don't like coding and I'll support that

Comment: I've been coding for many years, and, IMO, a lot of teachers could be much better [and I used to be a student teaching assistant]. A crappy computer science teacher can sour the experience because they can't explain things well. Another way to learn is to take a big _working_ program, written by an expert, and _analyze_ it. Ask the question: Why did they do _that_ in _that_ way? It's one of the ways I learned. It's like "studying the masters" in art. Another way is surf around SO, just reading questions. Many answers come from expert coders with decades of knowledge/experience. Have faith ...